# Hyperledger Client

Tags: android, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created a Hyperledger Fabric using Hyperledger compose. Then i want to create a client based on the Android smartphone app to connect the Fabric server and also can send the info. 
I have no idea about it, who would like to give me some advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the same question asked on [Rocket Chat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=Hx2wyWRANFNC8NaS2) ?

The Composer Sample Application "Vehicle Manufacture" has an element that works on a Mobile device which connects to the Composer REST server. It is the Car Builder part of the sample application.

The sample can be found here: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications/tree/master/packages/vehicle-manufacture

The sample uses the Ionic Framework for the mobile app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.